# Magento2 - Default shipping

Tags: magento2, cart, shipping

In my webshop I have two shipping methods, free shipping (for orders above 200 euro) and flat rate shipping (5 euro). I do not have other shipping methods for other countries or something.

I want to show the flat rate shipping if the order is under 200, else the free shipping method. I want to show this in the cart (not the estimate function, but as soon as the user goes to the cart it will see the appropriate shipping).

I created a plugin for the file: vendor/magento/module-tax/Block/Checkout/Shipping.php. This class has a function called `displayShipping`. This is called from the cart page to check if shipping should be displayed.

I created a before method for this function, so before Magento does the check it executes my function:

```
$shippingAddress = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
if (!$shippingAddress->getCountryId()) {
    $this
        ->getQuote()
        ->getShippingAddress()
        ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
        ->setCountryId('NL')
        ->save();
}
```

Now, shipping cost does show up in the cart, but the shipping amount is set to 0 instead of the 5 euro.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you got solution to it, If not let me know in comment

Answer (score 1):

I created an event :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index">
        <observer name="set-default-shipping-method" instance="Vendor\Checkout\Observer\SetDefaultShippingMethod"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

And in my event :

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Checkout\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;

use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class SetDefaultShippingMethod implements ObserverInterface
{
    /** @var CheckoutSession */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @param CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
     */
    public function __construct(CheckoutSession $checkoutSession) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();

        if(!$shippingAddress->getCountryId()){
            $shippingAddress->setCountryId('FR'); // Default country for calculate shipping rates if no one given
        }

        if(!$shippingAddress->getShippingMethod()){
            $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()->setShippingMethod('mondialrelay_pickup'); // Default Shipping method
        }


    }
}
```

This event is called when the user call the checkout cart index action

Comment: No. Its not working. event called but shipping method not selected.